# How can i use output of an aggregation as input to withColumn

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to profile some data using pyspark dataframes that contains strings, timestamps, integers and floats.

toy df:

```
sdf1 = 
|id1|id2|id3|
+---+---+---+
| 1 |"a"| 4 |
+---+---+---+
| 2 |"a"| 6 |
+---+---+---+
| 1 |"a"| 7 |
+---+---+---+
| 3 |"a"| 9 |
+---+---+---+


sdf2 = 
|ids|
+---+
|id1|
+---+
|id2|
+---+
|id3|
+---+
```

I am trying to achieve the following

`agg_instructions = [F.max(x).alias("{0}".format(x)) for x in sdf1.columns]`

`sdf3 = sdf2.withColumn("max", sdf1.agg(*agg_instructions))`

Which would result in the following dataframe.
However this does not work - any work around?

```
sdf3 = 
|ids|max|
+---+---+
|id1| 3 |
+---+---+
|id2|"a"|
+---+---+
|id3| 9 |
+---+---+
```

I get the following error:

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         7 agg_instructions = [F.max(x).alias("{0}".format(x)) for x in data_sdf.columns]
>         8 
>   ----> 9 sdf3 = sdf2.withColumn("max", sdf1.agg(*agg_instructions))
>        10 
>        11 test = test.reset_index()
>
> /databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in withColumn(self,
>   colName, col)    2011     2012         """
>   -> 2013         assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"    2014         return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc),
>   self.sql_ctx)    2015
>
> AssertionError: col should be Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too much for what you want to achieve. You can get the desired output from just `sdf1`.

One way is to create an array column that holds structs of column name and their corresponding max. Then explode it and select the struct fields.

Here is an example:

```
data = [(1, "a", 4), (2, "a", 6), (1, "a", 7), (3, "a", 9)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id1", "id2", "id3"])

agg_instructions = array(
        *[struct(lit(c).alias("ids"), max(col(c)).cast("string").alias("max")) for c in df.columns]
    )

df.agg(agg_instructions.alias("agg")) \
  .withColumn("agg", explode(col("agg"))) \
  .select("agg.*") \
  .show()

#+---+---+
#|ids|max|
#+---+---+
#|id1|3  |
#|id2|a  |
#|id3|9  |
#+---+---+
```